# How can I append packets in Java?

Tags: java, server, netty, packet

I have a simple client/server system build with `Netty` and I send data using packets.
A `Packet` in my case has two methods to write and read from a `BytBuf`.
For example a packet which contains strings gets the bytes from a string and writs them to a `ByteBuf`, which then is sent, or it reads the bytes from the `ByteBuf` and creates the message.
Here's the code snippet from my packet interface:

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;

public abstract class Packet {

    public abstract void read(ByteBuf byteBuf);

    public abstract void write(ByteBuf byteBuf);
}
```

First, when a packet is received, I want to check if there is a packet attached, and then I want to access or read it.

The problem is the instantiation of the packet when it is received. I could append a second packet to another and store it in a local variable of the first packet, but it is gone when i use `Class.newInstance()` to recreate the packet on the server-side.

Also the ByteBuf from Netty is not able to read or write own classes as far as i know...

My only idea is to send multiple packages, can i avoid that?

## EDIT

***Definition of the packet system i use.***

Because of the not well explained packet system i shortly tell what it does:

A packet in my case wrappes around the `ByteBuf`. In `Netty` the only way to send data is to write it on a `ByteBuf` in form of bytes. An example for a String based packet would be:

```
package com.sxf.protocol.chat.util.packets;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;

public class MessagePacket extends Packet {

    private String msg;

    public MessagePacket() {}

    public MessagePacket(String message) {
        this.msg = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void read(ByteBuf byteBuf) {
        byte[] msgBytes = new byte[byteBuf.readInt()];
        byteBuf.readBytes(msgBytes);

        msg = new String(msgBytes);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(ByteBuf byteBuf) {
        byte[] msgBytes = msg.getBytes();

        byteBuf.writeInt(msgBytes.length);
        byteBuf.writeBytes(msgBytes);
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

When you create the `Packet` you have to add the message in the form of a `String`. In the process of encoding i call `write()` and pass the `ByteBuf` which is sent through the pipeline. The message is then formed to bytes and written to the `ByteBuf`.

The same happens at the decoding, just the other way around.

I hope it gets clear so.

Comment: This is very broad. Can you provide a bit more detail? Can you provide examples of what you have done so far? 


Please refer to
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  What is a packet?  What is a message?   What does it *mean* for a packet to be attached to a message?  How does this relate to netty `ByteBuf`?  From what I can tell, this class is a general purpose "holder of a sequence of bytes" and it doesn't have an notion of things being attached to it.  Or messages.  Or packets.

Comment: It is even worse now.  You have now added the concepts that a custom class has bytes.  And packages.   Your terminology is terribly confusing.  I have a feeling that you have a rather nebulous conceptual design in your head.  Unfortunately, you need to describe it in clear and precise terms (preferably using well-defined terminology).  And I suspect that is either  going to be too hard, or is going to make the text of your Question ... pages long..

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of netty and sending packets?

Comment: Do you mean `DatagramPacket`?   Yes I am familiar with Datagrams.  But datagrams don't have things attached to them.   And a `ByteBuf` is not a `DatagramPacket`.  And now you are talking about packets attached to packets.  Really very confusing,

Comment: I don't mean ``DatagramPackets``

Comment: So what netty API class are you talking about?

Comment: I wrote the class ``Packet``. The class provides two methods where you pass a ``ByteBuf``. All classes which implements ``Packet`` are different types of packets to send different data. The data is transformed to bytes which are added to the ``ByteBuf``. Then the packet and the bytebuf are send.  The server than recreates the packet using ``Class.newInstance()``. And in the end you get your full recovered Packet-class by reading from the bytebuf which stored the e.g. String or int or whatever

Comment: I will add more code to make it less confusing

Comment: Well this is not something mentioned in the Netty documentation AFAIK.  I did see a youtube video (in german!) and mention of using netty to send Minecraft packets.   But this is not standard netty terminology AFAIK.   For example in https://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-5.x.html ... "packet" clearly means network packet.

Comment: So my packet and the network packet (hopefully) are the same. When i understand it correctly the network packet is a wrapper for the data. In the case of netty you have the problem with not sending packets but sending data in the form of bytes. The packet now wraps the data and then writes it to the final container, the bytebuf. in the end the packet is recreated and gets the back the data...

Comment: but i think i know how to solve my problem now !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not create Packet classes. I would just use a `BufferedOutputStream` to send the data manually or an `ObjectOutputStream` if you want to send whole objects. You may also inform the remote of what you send (send a String or anything else before appending the data).

e.g.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q56304773;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class PacketSender {
    private OutputStream networkStream;
    public void sendObject(Object o,String objInfo) throws IOException {
        try(BufferedOutputStream out=new BufferedOutputStream(getNetworkStream());
                ObjectOutputStream objectSender=new ObjectOutputStream(out);
                PrintWriter infoWriter=new PrintWriter(out)){
            infoWriter.printf("Object:%s", objInfo);
            objectSender.writeObject(o);
        }
    }
    public OutputStream getNetworkStream() {
        return networkStream;
    }
    public void setNetworkStream(OutputStream networkStream) {
        this.networkStream = networkStream;
    }
}


package com.stackoverflow.q56304773;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class PacketResciever {
    private InputStream networkStream;
    public void resv() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try(BufferedInputStream in=new BufferedInputStream(getNetworkStream());
                BufferedReader infoReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))){
            String header=infoReader.readLine();
            String[] splitted=header.split(":");
            switch(splitted[0]) {
                case "Object":
                    handleObject(new ObjectInputStream(in).readObject(),splitted[1]);
                    break;
                //other cases
            }

        }
    }
    private void handleObject(Object readObject,String info) {
        //search for handler and execute it
    }
    public InputStream getNetworkStream() {
        return networkStream;
    }
    public void setNetworkStream(InputStream networkStream) {
        this.networkStream = networkStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get your point. But i'm not sure if Netty supports sending Streams, as far as i know you have to convert all your data to bytes and add it to a ByteBuf

Comment: Use a DataInputStream and a DataOutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way is to have a packet attached to another is by adding a variable and a few methods to the class like this:

```
package com.sxf.protocol.chat.util.packets;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;

public abstract class Packet {

    private Packet attached;

    public abstract void read(ByteBuf byteBuf);

    public abstract void write(ByteBuf byteBuf);

    public final boolean isLinked() {
        return attached != null;
    }

    public final void append(Packet packet) {
        attached = packet;
    }

    public final Packet getAttached() {
        if (isLinked()) {
            return attached;
        }

        throw new NullPointerException("unsafe access to getAttached");
    }
}
```

With `append()` are you able to add a packet and store the passed packet.
`isLinked()` return wether a packet was attached or not.
`getAttached()` return the appended packet.

In the encoder you check if a packet is added and if so just recall the encode-method with the added packet. Like this:

```
    if (packet.isLinked()) {
            out.writeBoolean(true);
            encode(ctx, packet.getAttached(), out);
    } else {
            out.writeBoolean(false);
    }
```

Same for the decoder and your custom `ChannelInboundHandler`.